# Change background color of parent form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been looking for a couple of days for an answer and couldn't find one. I have a C# WPF application where I'm displaying the pc time, when i click on the application itself it opens another WPF form where I want to edit the background of the main form background so far I have this:

```
    MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainwindow.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)sliderRed.Value, (byte)sliderGreen.Value, (byte)sliderBlue.Value));
    }
```

So far as I see it should be fine but it is not editing the background. Sorry if this is a nub question I am quite new to coding and could not find an answer to the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are changing background of a new Window that you never show. You need to some how get a reference to the main window in the second (color picker) window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options;
1) If wanting to change a parents forms properties from within a child form, pass a reference through the constructor.
2) And the more common for what appears to be a "dialog" implementation and thus the one I will go into more detail on is to create a public property in the child form then read it from within the parent after the child is closed.

```
public class MainForm()
{

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorPicker ColorDialog = new ColorPicker();
        ColorDialog.ShowDialog(); // This will block until the child is closed as a true dialog normally does.
        this.Background = ColorDialog.ChosenColor;
    }
}

public class ColorPicker()
{
    public SolidColorBrush ChosenColor{get;private set;}

// Write the code for your color picker then store the value in ChosenColor.
}
```

This is just the basics to get you to the next step, a full implementation would also make use of the dialog result property to check if the dalog was closed or if an actual color was picked.